# Is it possible to store array into object array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, togglebutton

I have 30 `JToggleButton`. If they get pressed, I want to pass the i and the title into another class .

```
confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        boolean buttonClicked = false;
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            if (ButtonList[i].isSelected()) {
                buttonClicked = true;

                System.out.print(i+1);
                System.out.println(title);
                pass(title, ButtonList[i]);
            }
        }
        if (!buttonClicked) {
            JFrame parent= new JFrame();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "You haven't select a seat");
        }
    }
});
```

Before calling past() function, I did a test here. The number of title printed seems following the total number of toggleButton clicked. How to avoid this ?

The above code give me this output (Assume 2 toggle button clicked )

> 1Marvel's Captain America
>
> 2Marvel's Captain America

Comment: Literally going off your title: yes, you can store an array in an `Object[]`. But I can't quite see how the title relates to your question.

Comment: @AndyTurner sir can you tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: It doesn't seem easy to me, because I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @AndyTurner Sir why you delete your answer ?

Comment: Because I can't be bothered to deal with questions that change after I've answered.

Comment: @AndyTurner Sorry sir, I thought you not understand my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to pass all the selected seats for the specified movie?

```
    Set<Integer> selectedSeats = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) 
    {
        if (ButtonList[i].isSelected()) 
        {
            selectedSeats.add(i + 1);
        }
    }

    if (selectedSeats.isEmpty()) 
    {
        JFrame parent= new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "You haven't select a seat");
    }
    else
        pass(title, selectedSeats);
```

Comment: `buttonClicked == !selectedSeats.isEmpty()`. No need for a separate variable. Also, I think `pass` should only be called if `buttonClicked` is true.

Comment: I don't think I understood you. What do you mean? your solution also contains a seperate variable

Comment: Nope, just `pressedButtonIndexes`.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how can I store the array i into a object so that it
>   can pass with the title in a new function called pass() ?

so, I understood that you want to inform a method named "pass" with the title and the items that it was selected. If that's the case, you could do something like:

```
pass(list, title);
```

using the code below (using ArrayList you dont need to use the "buttonClicked"  boolean):

```
confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ArrayList<int> list = new ArrayList<int>();

        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            if (ButtonList[i].isSelected()) {
                list.add(i);
            }
        }                       
        if (list.size() == 0) {
            JFrame parent= new JFrame();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "You haven't select a seat");
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.

EDIT: Andy Turner you're right, I just changed it

Comment: `if (list.size() > 0) {` is the inverse of the desired condition.

Comment: Should be `ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Answer (score 0):

The class that wants to receive the data could implement the the ActionListener interface. Then you could use that class instead of a new ActionListener.

Here how that could look like:

```
public class ClassThatWantsEvents implements ActionListener{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { ...
```

and how you would use it in your current class:

```
confirm.addActionListener(ClassThatWantsEvents);
```

Comment: That's not the answer I looking for. Anywhere, thanks for your help